# Get balance for an array of addresses with bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, balance, bitcore

I am searching for a command to get balance for imported addresses in bitcoin (not my wallet addresses) and I don't wanna do this with blockchain explorer API's. Is it possible to do this through bitcoin core? if not, is there any alternative option like bitcore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scantxoutset` command. This will scan the utxo set and return the utxos and the total balance for the addreses that you specify. Because it scans the utxo set, you won't have the transaction history for those addresses. But it does get you the balance and a list of utxos that can be used in a new transaction.